# In variable product Buy Now Button showing two times

Tags: button, plugins

For Buy Now I'm using one plugin (WPC Buy Now Button for WooCommerce) and one Buy Now function for showing Buy Now on Homepage, But when I create variable product Buy Now button showing two times please help me out.
I’m using latest Version 1.2.4 plugin name
WPC Buy Now Button for WooCommerce
variable product URL https://shorturl.at/azLSZ

also write buy now button code for home page

`add_action('wcps_layout_element_add_to_cart','wcps_layout_element_post_title_20200331', 90); function wcps_layout_element_post_title_20200331($args){ $product_id = isset($args['product_id']) ? $args['product_id'] : ''; $elementData = isset($args['elementData']) ? $args['elementData'] : array();$element_index = isset($args['element_index']) ? $args['element_index'] : '';  echo do_shortcode("[wpcbn_btn_archive id='$product_id']"); }`

I'm just try to hide 1 button but it's not working